# Best Plugin to notify the new job and configuration changes in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

What is the best plugin to be used in the Jenkins to notify the creation of the New job and the any changes in the Jenkins ?

Comment: I use the [Job Config History](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) plugin.  *It monitors config.xml file of all the jobs and jenkins.xml too.   *It also adds a link on each job and your jenkins home page titled 'Job Config History' and it lists all the changes made.  *You can also revert your  changes back to an earlier version

Answer (score 4):

Two Plugins:

Job Config History, for job changes:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin

Audit Trail Plugin, For job creation/deletion/execution/etc:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin

Comment: Warning: Job config history's 2015-1211 release, the most recent since 2014-0824, has a bug on all operating systems where the Jenkins GUI is mangled after installing it. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32124

Answer (score 2):

And one based on syncing Jenkins changes to SCM:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin